# Which root locus is better and why?

Tags: control, matlab, electrical

[image]

which root locus is better out of these two, and what is the reason?

Comment: Better in what way?

Comment: the system, which one are more preferred

Comment: The 2nd plot has ringing; can you exploit that?

Comment: I think the sideways smiley one looks cuter.  Go with that.

Answer (score 2):

Root locus is just a visual representation of the system response as you vary the gain (generally, the part you control). Sometimes overdamped is preferred, sometimes critically, and sometimes underdamped (some oscillation). Which is better depends on your specifications for the system, so no one root locus is inherently preferred. While oscillation generally isn't preferred it can be exploited for improving other aspects of the system. The goal generally is to balance stability, rise time, and settling time requirements. Further, you can always manipulate the root locus via things like PID controllers, which can allow you to add poles and zeroes.

Comment: Tq for your information, really appreciate it. God bless you.

Answer (score 1):

Which is better, depends on the application. \$A\$ is overdamped, \$B\$ may be underdamped or overdamped, as determined by the gain setting.

\$A\$ will be insensitive to variations in the loop gain (either intentional or unintentional), so in that sense it will be robust. \$B\$ allows one of it's performance characteristics to be set by the loop gain, which gives flexibility, but drift in the gain value may affect the prominent response features.

Comment: Tq for this information. It really help me. God bless you.